# Remote desktop: remote USB devices not recognized

Tags: windows, usb, remote-desktop

[Update] **I do *not* want to redirect the USB device!** I'm trying to use a remote device on the remote computer, just like it would if I'd not using remote desktop.

I'm connected to a remote computer using remote Desktop.

When I now connect a USB stick (or any other USB device) to the remote computer, it does not get recognized. 
To get the stick recognized I Need to disconnect from the remote Computer, log me in locally on the remote Computer, connect the USB device.
If I connect to the remote Computer after the USB device has been recognized, it will work flawlessly.

But this is annoying. How do I get the remote Computer to recognize USB devices connected to the remote computer while using a remote Connection?

(this is not about USB redirection - the USB device is local to the remote computer, not to the local computer)

Comment: Open up device manager and do scan for hardware changes?

Comment: Did not work, sadly.